# How to manage a handling angularjs HTTP error with MVC custom page error?

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio, model-view-controller

•   I need to manage page not found and server problem errors by redirect to my own custom error pages, so I done this by following, and its working fine.

**web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On">  
<error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/Error400"/>  
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/Error404" />  
<error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Error403" />  
<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Errors/Error500" />  
</customErrors>
```

•   so now when I need to get the `angularjs http` errors like 404 by following code in which passing wrong method (GetDetai) which is not available in controller (actual is 'GetDetails').

```
$http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: '/Admin/Dashboard/GetDetai',  
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }  
     }).then(function (result) {  
        console.log(result);  
        $scope.GetCustomer = result.data;  
        }, function (reason) {  
                console.log(reason);  
            if (reason.status == '404') {  
                console.log('Invalid Method/URL.');  
            }  
            else if (reason.status == '505') {  
                console.log('Internal server error.');  
            }  
        });
```

•    then its not catching the 404 error in error function, its going into then function and displaying below

**First Console log Output**

```
{data: "
↵
↵
↵<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵<head>
↵    <meta c…white;">Go Back To Home</a>
↵</body>
↵</html>
↵
↵", status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ, …}
data: "
↵
↵
↵<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵<head>
↵    <meta charset="utf-8" />
↵    <title></title>
↵    <style>
↵        body {
↵            display: inline-block;
↵            background: #00AFF9 url(https://cbwconline.com/IMG/Codepen/Unplugged.png) center/cover no-repeat;
↵            height: 100vh;
↵            margin: 0;
↵            color: white;
↵        }
↵
↵        h1 {
↵            margin: .8em 3rem;
↵            font: 4em Roboto;
↵        }
↵
↵        p {
↵            display: inline-block;
↵            margin: .2em 3rem;
↵            font: 2em Roboto;
↵        }
↵    </style>
↵</head>
↵<body>
↵    <h1>Whoops!</h1>
↵    <p>Something went wrong</p><br /><br />
↵    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
↵    <a href="/Home/Index" style="color:white;">Go Back To Home</a>
↵</body>
↵</html>
↵
↵"
status: 200
headers: ƒ (name)
config: {method: "GET", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", paramSerializer: ƒ, …}
statusText: "OK"
xhrStatus: "complete"
__proto__: Object
```

•    But when I commented/removed that web.config custom error code then this `angularjs http` call error function working properly, getting expected 404 error.

So How to manage these both kind of errors properly with non dependencies and non effect on other codes?

Comment: Do note that the response you are getting is `status: 200` in your "Firsr error" code sample. That means the website you are retrieving does not return the proper [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) when errors happen.

Comment: but its not catching in error function, its coming from then function

Comment: @abbasarman because your server is having `status: 200` in response.check the FIRST_ERROR you have shared. The server should return `404`. Can you share exact url call from Network Tab. ? (please comment domain name and all sensitive info)

Comment: @abbasarman : Also, on local use `angular.js` and not `angular.min.js` , your angular 
 error is more readable when using `angular.js`

Comment: @Shashank Vivek I updated my quession, please check that is it you asking as per my understand?

Comment: @abbasarman : You can see that status is `200` . The server should return `404` when calling `/Admin/Dashboard/GetDetai` rather than `/Admin/Dashboard/GetDetails`. There is nothing you can do from client side

Comment: @Shashank Vivek I was not mentioned that I am using custom error page by doing 'customError mode=on' in web.config file, and redirecting to my own error page so thats why here getting that page html code in data and status code 200, when I commented that then getting as per I expect i.e, 404. so how to manage this both of them?

Comment: @abbasarman: That makes sense now. You need to send 404 error code to let the UI do its thing. Otherwise you'll have to check `<html>` pattern in all response to differentiate. that would be so wrong.

Comment: It becomes difficult to understand the problem. Please edit your question and better rephrase your question, the cases you meet, what you can or cannot modify ... etc. Use Google Translate if you can't write the question in English in an understandable way.

Comment: @Stephane Janicaud I updated now, is it ok now?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP call returned status "200" which is "OK" so you cannot see HTTP ERRORS
Error raised in processing retrieved data:

```
$http({
  ... 
})
.then(
  function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    //Line below is not invoked as result.data != "Exception"
    if (result.data == "Exception") {
        ... 
    }
    else {
        ...
        //This assignes result.data to GetCustomer in scope 
        //and at late stage of processing retrieved data rose exception... 
        $scope.GetCustomer = result.data;
    }
  }, 
  function (reason) { //This code is not invoking as http.resultCode="200" ("OK")
    ...
  }
);
```

Comment: so why is status code  200 is coming where as which method name I passing in URL is not available in my controller, so should invoke status code 404 na

Comment: @abbasarman "why is status code 200?" easy answer, poorly made website, should have returned an 404 status code but it does not. In your screenshot you can see it returns 200 (OK status code)

Comment: poorly made website means?

Comment: I was not mentioned that I am using custom error page by doing 'customError mode=on' in web.config file, and redirecting to my own error page so thats why here getting that page html code in data and status code 200, when I commented that then getting as per I expect i.e, 404. so how to manage this both of them?

Answer (score 0):

@ShashankVivek is 100% right, your server should return a HTTP_NOT_FOUND (404) error when calling an invalid endpoint.

Until the problem is fixed on the server side, you can verify that the returned result does not contain a pattern indicating that it is an HTML document and not a JSON document, for example `<DOCTYPE html>`

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/Admin/Dashboard/GetDetai",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
}).then(
  function (result) {
    // hack to check if an error occurred on server-side
    if(/<!DOCTYPE html>/.test(result)) {
      throw new Error({status: 500});
    } // end of hack
    ...
  },
  function (reason) {
    if (reason.status == "404") {
      growl.warning("Connection lost.", { title: "Warning!" });
    } else if (reason.status == "505") {
      growl.warning("Invalid Methode/Url.", { title: "Warning!" });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I was not mentioned that I am using custom error page by doing 'customError mode=on' in web.config file, and redirecting to my own error page so thats why here getting that page html code in data and status code 200, when I commented that then getting as per I expect i.e, 404. so how to manage this both of them?

Comment: if you now receive a 404 your code must pass into error function with the reason ?

Comment: yes its passing into the error, but I need that custom error page too by which I can catch page not found and server error e.t.c, so when I using this custom page error then angular http not getting into the error function